# Recursive function to find first alphabetic character

Tags: javascript

I have Javascript code where I take a large piece of text, separate it at each period, load it into an array, and remove any html tags using replace(). Then, I need to use a recursive function to find the first alphabetic character in the string because I want to put specific formatting on the first alphabetic character. To me, it should be at substring(0,1)...

...the problem is, I came across this issue where the first alphabetic character is usually substring(2,3) but not always. So I wrote the recursive function below. The problem is the character at 0,1,2, and sometimes 3 is not a blank space but it's not an alphabetic character. If I do eval(), it's 'undefined'. But my recursive function is failing when I eval() after the 'undefined' characters. I'm missing something but not sure what.

Any ideas how I can test for those first characters that are 'undefined'? I suppose they are a result of the replace().

```
function getFirstLetter(text,count){
    // If first time calling the function, count will be null so set to 0
    if(count == null){
        count = 0; 
    }

    // Get the character at the count index
    thisChar = eval(text.charAt(count));

    // Is this character the first alphabetic character? If so, return
    // Here's where the problem occurs...I've noticed that the function
    // will return 'undefined' for the first few non-alphabetic characters
    // but then it stops at the first alphabetic character, no idea why
    if(thisChar != 'undefined' && thisChar != null){
        return count; 
    }else{
        // If not, call the function again for the next index
        getFirstLetter(text,count+1); 
    }
}
```

Example array text:

```
Here is a line of text, Here is the next line, And the next line
```

But if I check each of the first characters, I don't get an alphabetic character or a blank space. When I do alert(array.charAt(0)) I get an alert with nothing in it. There's no blank space in the alert.

Comment: Is the idea behind using `eval` that "if it's not a letter, it must be a number"? You may be better off with a short and simple regex. Consider adding an example to this question, both a good match and a failing one.

Comment: why eval? i can't imagine that it's required. why do you need recursion for a flat array?

Comment: There’s a difference between `'undefined'` and `undefined`.

Comment: I'm using a recursive function because I want to test each character from the start of the string to see if it's an alphabetic character or not. The text comes from a CMS and it could have blanks at the beginning of it so I'm trying to make sure the first character is alphabetic and, if not, find the first one. I just can't be sure the first character is an alphabetic character. It could be blank.

Comment: It's odd. When I test it, the first character sometimes is just...blank. It's not a blank space. It's just nothing. I don't know why. I can only assume it's because elsewhere I do replace(/\<p>/gi,'')...I assumed it'd just remove the character but maybe it inputs a weird thing in the string?

Comment: `function getFirstLetter(text){ return text.search(/\w/) }`

Comment: What is search(/\w/) ? I'm confused what it does, but if it works I'm thrilled!

Comment: [`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) returns the index and `\w` means any “word character”. Alternatively, you can try `[a-zA-Z]` or whatever you need.

Comment: ***The blank space issue:*** There is no `Array.prototype.charAt`, only a `String.prototype.charAt`. If your test “object” is an array, then calling `charAt` on it won’t work. You can also try to work with your browser’s console and type `[` …test strings… `].charAt(0)` in it. It will throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: But I'm using substring(n,n)?

Comment: There’s also no `Array.prototype.substring` but a `String.prototype.substring`.

Comment: Then why would array[i].substring(2,3) usually work but not array[i].substring(0,1)?

Comment: Just use the console to experiment with the array and see what it returns… I can’t think of any explanation based on the available information either…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is a method utilising a regular expression like this:

```
function getFirstLetter(text){
  return text.search(/[a-zA-Z]/);
}
```

---

There are a few problems with your code:

1. If an argument is missing (e. g. `count`), it’ll be `undefined` in the function, not `null`
2. Checking for the *string* `'undefined'` instead of the intended special value `undefined`
3. Using `eval` seems kinda hacky and counter-intuitive in this case. Use the short-circuit OR operator `||` instead; then you only need one comparison — `thisChar != null` — anyways

Your code improved altogether:

```
function getFirstLetter(text,count){
    if(count == undefined){
        var count = 0; 
    }
    var thisChar = text.charAt(count)||null;
    if(thisChar != null){
        return count; 
    }
    else{
        getFirstLetter(text,count+1); 
    }
}
```

What you are left with, unfortunately, is a useless function that will either return a number or abort with an `InternalError: too much recursion` because either `charAt(` *n* `)` will have a low enough *n* to return *that character at n always* or it will increase the *n* and *always return `''` and therefore `null`*.

Therefore, stick with the RegExp solution above.

Comment: I usually check null if a parameter of a function doesn't have a value and it's always worked. I had no idea it should be undefined. I'll use that from now on. Yes, it seems I need a regex and not a recursive function. Thank you! I'll use the regex. It seems like /a-z/i works best. I tried search(/\w/) and it doesn't seem to work. It's always returning 1 even though I know that's not true, not sure why.

Comment: But...I still don't get why substring(0,1) didn't work even though it seems the first one or two characters aren't a blank space. There's some weird non-character thing in there. Very confused about that part of it.

Comment: `[a-z]`, not `a-z`. Well, an unset argument does _return_ `undefined`, but then again `undefined == null` which is why it probably worked…

Comment: Yes, sorry. I put [a-z] in my code but typed it "a-z" here. I apologize. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you’d supply some examples and expected and actual results for those then we’d be happy to debug that problem as well. =)